# Selenium unable to find elements on this site

Tags: c#, selenium

On the following website: https://netbank.nedsecure.co.za
there is an inputbox for profile number.

However, Selenium is unable to find the element and throws a NoSuchElementException. I have tried what is suggested in other Stackoverflow questions, regarding using a wait to ensure the page has loaded.

Here is some code that fails:

```
 var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
 var driver = new ChromeDriver(path);
 driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
 driver.Url = "https://netbank.nedsecure.co.za";
 var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
 wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(By.Id("ProfileId")));
 var profileInput = driver.FindElementById("ProfileId");
```

Comment: I won't be able to check the web site directly since my employer will probably have it blocked, it would have been better if you could have posted in your original question a large section of the HTML code.  It's possible that the element you are looking for is inside an IFRAME

Comment: Not an iframe, but it is located inside a <frameset> which contains a <frame>
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_frames.htm

Comment: Based upon what I read there, and on the IFrame section, I think that might be your problem.  Selenium needs to select a frame.  I've only ever experienced this with IFrames but I would think that frames would be the same at least in how Selenium would handle it.

Comment: Yeah, the frame is the issue. I've resolved it. Thanks. I wouldn't have figured that out if you didn't mention looking for an iframe

Comment: Glad I could help!  After 24 hours, I think, you'll be able to mark your own answer as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page had a `<frameset>` with a `<frame>` element. 
The issue is resolved by switching the driver to the frame

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("frameMain");
```

Answer (score 0):

Profile Number, PIN & Password & Login button are present on a frame. You need to switch on a frame before performing any action on it. Please use below code to switch on your frame.

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.id("frameset")));
```